# Android Studio: I am receiving an error when trying to implement OKHTTP3 into the build.gradle

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, build.gradle, okhttp

I'm getting the following error in android studio when I add OKHTTP3 to the app level build.gradle and attempt to sync the build.gradle:

`ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0.`

My code for implementing the dependency looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0'
    ...
}
```

This is the latest version of OKHTTP3 that I took from https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/4.4.0/jar so this should work fine.

In the project level build.gradle I have `jcenter()` included within the repositories at both the *buildscript* and *allprojects* levels so I am unsure why I am receiving the above error as, from other stackoverflow questions, I can see that `jcenter()` is the maven central repository which this library comes from.

I have looked at all other stackoverflow questions on this matter but none of their solutions are working for me and I am receiving the same error regardless of any attempts.

I appreciate any suggestion anyone may have. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try adding google() repo as well.

Comment: You may try `mavenCentral()`

Comment: @ShadabAnsari I have tried this but I am unfortunately getting the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @PrajwalW the google() repo already exists in there. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into the above problem. This is what worked for me:

I did some research into the new Android Studio version as I figured out that I had done everything else correctly and the error was most likely to do with the recent Android Studio update. To fix the above solution, I toggled the `build.gradle` offline mode to off which resolved the entire problem.

To perform the same steps, this is taken from Android Studio's 3.6 blog post:

> New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

**This post can be found here https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#gradle-offline-ui**